# Evaluating a Real Improper Integral by Residues

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

I am having trouble evaluating this improper integral due to its integrand and the singularities that are present. The question reads as

> Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^4+1}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$.
>   The contour is assumed to be the boundary of the half disc $|z|\leq R, Im(z)\geq 0$ taken once anticlockwise. You may assume that the integrals converge.

The questions that I have been solving have had "nice" singularities; in the form of $x+iy,x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. I understand the process that takes place in this case. However, this particular integrand has singularities (inside the boundary) of $z=i^{1/2},i^{3/2}$. This is already an intuitive problem. How does one situate these singularities inside the boundary and thus progress with calculations? Furthermore, if I continue with the methodic process I will not get the answer.

Thank you in advanced for you help.

Comment: You need to find the zero's of the denominator and identify the zero's that are in the upper half plane. These zeros you need to establish your sum of the residues.

Comment: @imranfat. Yes. I am well aware of this. If you read the last paragraph - my specific problem is described there. Perhaps I'm stupid :( . Do you mind typing a quick solution?. My singularities aren't yielding what I need.

Comment: Setting $x^4+1=(x^2+i)(x^2-i)=0$ Gives $x^2=i$ and $x^2=-i$ Do you know how to solve these? Each equation gives a solution in the upper half plane

Comment: So the singularities should be at $z=i^{1/2}$ and $z=i^{3/2}$?

Comment: You need to find the complex numbers $a+bi$ that satisfy these equations. So in case of the first equation, the argument of $i$ is 90 degrees and so taking half of it is 45 (the other one we don't need). The abs. value of $i$ is $1$ so that doesn't change. One of the two solutions for our residues is $0.5+0.5iSqrt 2$, please forgive my formatting.

Comment: The formatting is fine. Forgive me for still not understanding :(. You're saying that $x=0.5+0.5\sqrt{2}i$ is a solution to the equation $x^2=i$. I just subbed it in. I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: Oh yes !!!! I understand what you are saying now ! But the solution to the first is actually $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)$. Thanks a lot man ! This should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factorization is $(x+0.5+0.5i) \sqrt2)(x-0.5+0.5i) \sqrt2)(x+0.5-0.5i)\sqrt2)(x-0.5-0.5i) \sqrt2)$ The third and fourth factor provide the root in the upper half plane.
To find the residues: Knock out the third factor and substitute its roots in the fraction. That's one residue. And then, knock out the fourth factor (put the third back of course) and then put in its root in the fraction. Now you have two residues. Add them up and multiply by $2 \pi i$. That should do it. It's time for me to sleep now. Good luck

Comment: the four 0.5's need a squareroot 2 along with it, I forgot.